# Android - what is the code needed for serving Facebook ads?

Tags: android, facebook

I just imported the Facebook library for Android and according to their tutorials, what I see is that I have to add this to every Activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume ()
{
    super.onResume();

    Settings.publishInstallAsync ( getApplicationContext( ) , "app_id" );
}
```

Is that correct? Or is there something extra I have to do in the code? And does it have to be only in the first activity? Or every activity?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to call that in your main activity (the one that launches your app).